# Access denied Error installing ffmpeg with choco

Tags: powershell, installation, ffmpeg, chocolatey, manim

I was trying the command '''choco install ffmpeg''' but the following error appear

ffmpeg not installed. An error occurred during installation:
Access denied to path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ffmpeg\legal'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common reason for this is that you may not be running choco from an administrative shell; make sure you start the shell as administrator before running the command.

If you already are, or that does not resolve the issue, it's possible there's an issue with the `ffmpeg` package itself, and it may be worth contacting the package maintainer via the links on the community repository to get it addressed.